# Python Tornado: Delete request never ends

Tags: python, rest, tornado, python-3.4

I am having problems with a delete request in Tornado. The request arrives to the server and everything in the handler work great, but it never returns the response to the client.

I have tried returning something, with only the "return" and even without the "return" and the result is always the same.

I am using Python 3.4, Tornado 4.1 and the RestClient of Firefox.

```
@web.asynchronous
@gen.coroutine
def delete(self, _id):
    try:
        model = Model()
        model.delete(_id)
        self.set_status(204)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)
        self.set_status(500)
    return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tornado documentation ([tornado.web.asynchronous](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/web.html?highlight=web.asynchronous#tornado.web.asynchronous)):

> If this decorator is given, the response is not finished when the method > returns. It is up to the request handler to call self.finish() to finish > the HTTP request.

You need to call tornado.web.RequestHandler.finish method. This will work:

```
@web.asynchronous
@gen.coroutine
def delete(self, _id):
    try:
        model = Model()
        model.delete(_id)
        self.set_status(204)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)
        self.set_status(500)
    self.finish()
    return
```

However, you don't need asynchronous approach in this example. This will work also in the same way:

```
def delete(self, _id):
    try:
        model = Model()
        model.delete(_id)
        self.set_status(204)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)
        self.set_status(500)
    return
```

Also, if you are using @gen.coroutine decorator, you don't need to use @web.asynchronous decorator. Simply use only @gen.coroutine, it is the correct way and much more elegant.

Lastly, I think you should read [this article](http://www.maigfrga.ntweb.co/asynchronous-programming-tornado-framework/) for understanding asynchronous programming in Tornado.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried your different approaches but no of them have worked. Even I have begun to yield the result of the delete (something that I don't need) in order to wait for the action and the result is the same. Maybe the problem is related to the firefox restclient, because debugging the code it seems to finish, but no response arrives to the client.

Comment: If the delete method does not return a Future object, you don't have to yield its result.

Comment: Hi,

I have tried all the possibilities and the final solution has been to change the status from 204 to 202 (Accepted) assuming that the action (delete and even put) will be executed asynchronously and write and a response. Do you know if there are any problems when we put status 204 or 206 ?

Thanks.

Comment: The problem was the firefox rest plugin. 

Thanks.